# Rails AR: Fetching most visited rooms for a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have the following:

```
class Visit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user, :room

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :room
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :visited_rooms, through: :visits, source: :room
  has_many :visits
  ...
end
```

How can I return the most visited rooms for a specific user? the only thing I came up with is:
`user.visits.include(:room).order("count DESC")`

And then fetch the rooms from each visit instance.
Isn't there a way to only fetch the rooms, without the need for visits?

Something like `user.visits.rooms` didn't work...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about?

```
user.visited_rooms.includes(:visits).order('visits.count DESC')
```

Comment: Nice one, Actually I thought of `scope :most_visited_for, lambda { |user| joins(:visits).where("visits.user_id = ?", user.id).order('visits.count DESC') }` but I believe your's is even better :) thanks!